# How to take shape [1,1,256] from [1,4,256] cuda.FloatTensor?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have an batch of output hidden vector from GRU. It's shape is [1,4,256]

```
( 0 ,.,.) = 
-0.9944  1.0000  0.0000  ...  -1.0000  0.0000 -1.0000
-1.0000  1.0000  0.0000  ...  -1.0000  0.0000 -1.0000
-1.0000  1.0000  0.0000  ...  -1.0000  0.0000 -1.0000
-1.0000  1.0000  0.0000  ...  -1.0000  0.0000 -1.0000
[torch.cuda.FloatTensor of size (1,4,256) (GPU 0)]
```

I need a shape of [1,1,256] to pass to another model. How can I take it? Through this line I can only have a shape of [1,256]

```
decoder_hidden = encoder_hidden[:, index]
```

resize and wrap a new FloatTensor didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**unsqueeze()**](http://pytorch.org/docs/0.3.1/torch.html#torch.unsqueeze) in dimension `1` to achieve this.

```
encoder_hidden = torch.randn(1, 4, 256)
print(encoder_hidden.size())

for idx in range(encoder_hidden.size(1)):
    decoder_hidden = encoder_hidden[:, idx, :].unsqueeze(1)
    print(decoder_hidden.size())
```

It prints:

```
torch.Size([1, 4, 256])
torch.Size([1, 1, 256])
torch.Size([1, 1, 256])
torch.Size([1, 1, 256])
torch.Size([1, 1, 256])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`view()`](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.view) method of tensors.

```
decoder_hidden_new = decoder_hidden.view((1, 1, 256))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here're more ways to do this. Details in the comments below:

```
# random tensor
In [53]: t.shape
Out[53]: torch.Size([1, 4, 256])

# the four slices
In [54]: slice_1 = t[:, 0, :]
In [55]: slice_2 = t[:, 1, :]
In [56]: slice_3 = t[:, 2, :]
In [57]: slice_4 = t[:, 3, :]

In [58]: slice_1.shape
Out[58]: torch.Size([1, 256])

# using `torch.np.newaxis`
In [59]: slice_1 = slice_1[torch.np.newaxis, ...]

In [60]: slice_1.shape
Out[60]: torch.Size([1, 1, 256])

# simply using `np.newaxis`
In [61]: slice_2 = slice_2[np.newaxis, ...]

In [62]: slice_2.shape
Out[62]: torch.Size([1, 1, 256])

# or even simply, use `None` which is an alias to `np.newaxis`
In [63]: slice_3 = slice_3[None, ...]

In [64]: slice_3.shape
Out[64]: torch.Size([1, 1, 256])
```